# Angular promises: get data from buffer if available

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this scenario the requirement is to get the data with an Http request if the data is not in a buffer. If it's in the buffer, use it from there without the Http request.

I tried the code below but it doesn't make much sense; if the data is in the buffer I don't know if I should return from the function doing nothing or return the deferred promise. Any thoughts?

```
  var dataBuffer = null;

  var getData = function() {

     var deferred = $q.defer();

     if (dataBuffer != null) {  // this is the part I'm not convinced
         deferred.resolve();
         return;
     }  


     $http.get('/some/url/')
       .success(function(data) { 
               dataBuffer = data;
               deferred.resolve();
       })
       .error(function(data) {
               deferred.reject();
       });

     return deferred.promise;
  };
```

Invoked in the following way:

```
     var promise = getData();
     promise.then (
           function(response) { 
              dataBuffer = .... // dataBuffer contains data
              }
           );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). You can accomplish what you are trying to do very cleanly, like this:

```
var dataBuffer;
var getData = function() {
    if (dataBuffer) {
        // return a resolved promise for  dataBuffer  if it is already populated
        return $q.when(dataBuffer);
    }  

    $http.get('/some/url/')
    .then(function (data) { 
        dataBuffer = data.data;
        return dataBuffer;
    });
};

getData().then(function (data) { 
    // data contains the data you want
})
.catch(function (error) {
    // error occurred.
});
```

---

`dataBuffer` should not be accessed outside of your `getData` function. To make this perfectly clear, you can wrap them together in an IIFE, although this is optional:

```
var getData = (function () {
    var dataBuffer;
    return function() {
        if (dataBuffer) {
            // return a resolved promise for  dataBuffer  if it is already populated
            return $q.when(dataBuffer);
        }  

        $http.get('/some/url/')
        .then(function (data) { 
            dataBuffer = data.data;
            return dataBuffer;
        });
    };
})();

getData().then(..etc etc etc...);
```

---

As a final note, remember that you can use `$http`'s built-in caching features, and not have to reinvent the wheel with your own buffers:

```
// much simpler, isn't it?
var getData = function() {
    $http.get('/some/url/', { cache: true })  // enable caching
    .then(function (data) { return data.data });
};

getData().then(...etc etc etc...);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a clean simple way to use promises when you're not sure which is the code you're executing is asynchronous or not and it's using `$q.when`
So the code can be:

```
var getData = function() {
    return $q.when(dataBuffer ? dataBuffer: $http.get('/some/url')) 
};
```

Then when calling getData you can use the same code you posted or just simply:

```
getData()
       .then(function(response){//... 
       })
       .catch(function(err){//..
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you enable cache instead of handling the buffer manually.

```
   $http.get('/some/url/',{ cache: true})
   .success(function(data) { 
           deferred.resolve(data);
   })
   .error(function(data) {
           deferred.reject();
   });
```

Comment: `deferred.resolve(data)` you may want to access data in the success callback

Comment: I can't; I simplified the example but the scenario involves an array of data where each entry in the array is populated from the responses. Also, I would need to have control on when to clear the $http cache.

Comment: Can you provide more detail in your question then? I suspect that there is a better way to do what you are trying to do.